# R: knit a list of ggplotly generated figures in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, plotly, r-markdown

I have searched in `stackoverflow`, and there are similar questions, but the answers did not work in my case.

I want to generate a list of plots, and output them in HTML by knitting Rmarkdown file.

Here is a very simple demo code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
DF <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(1:10), C = (1:10))
myplots <- vector('list', ncol(DF))

for (i in 1: dim(DF)[2]) {
  p = ggplot(DF, aes(x = DF[, i], y = C)) +
    geom_point() 
  myplots[[i]] = plotly::ggplotly(p)
}

myplots[[1]]
myplots[[2]]
myplots[[3]]
```

If I index them, they can be plotted in HTML file.

```
myplots[[1]]
myplots[[2]]
myplots[[3]]
```

However, if I directly use the list object or loop it, none of the method worked:

```
# method 1
myplots

# method 2
for (i in seq_along(myplots)) print(myplots[[i]])

#nethod 3

for (i in 1:length(myplots)) print(myplots[[i]])
```

I don't understand the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Use `htmltools::tagList(myplots)` where you want them to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete answer, thanks a lot @user2554330

I need to first convert the list into `taglist`, and then convert it into a plotly `htmlwidget` object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
DF <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(1:10), C = (1:10))
myplots <- htmltools::tagList()

for (i in 1: dim(DF)[2]) {
  p = ggplot(DF, aes(x = DF[, i], y = C)) +
    geom_point() 
  myplots[[i]] = plotly::as_widget(plotly::ggplotly(p))
}

myplots
```